# Как пишется?

Tags: орфография

Как пишется "фото услуги" - слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 2):

Пишутся слитно сложные имена существительные с элементами авто-, агро-, аэро-, био-, вело-, гелио-, гео-, гидро-, зоо-, изо-, кино-, макро-, метео-, микро-, моно-, мото-, нео-, палео-, радио-, стерео-, теле-, фото-, электро- и др. независимо от числа названных элементов или других слов в основе. Поэтому Liana совершенно права: фотоуслуги, автомотовеломагазин  - в соответствии с правилами правописания.

Answer (score 0):

Слитное написание - фотоуслуги.

Comment: @Liana, Пожалуйста, поясните, на чем основано Ваше утверждение?